# how can I jump to the higher half kernel

Tags: c, kernel, virtual-memory, osdev, virtual-address-space

I am currently building a higher half kernel, my bootloader loads the kernel at physical address 0x100000(1M) and identity mapping has been set for 0-4MB. Here is the question: how can I jump to the higher virtual address(3GB,for example).

I Googled this question and have found two ways: one is to use the address space warp around and one is to set page entries to map 3GB~3GB+4MB to 0-4MB then "jump" to the higher address.I decided to use the second way but can't find enough information to implement it. I disassembled my kernel and found that all the addresses are absolute, so I believe that a single "jmp" instruction won't be suffice. The only way I can think about is that there is a function in virtual address above 3GB and we call this function in lower space then we will be excuting in high space and this function should never returned. If this is ture, how can I do this?

Comment: [Higher Half bare bones](http://wiki.osdev.org/Higher_Half_bare_bones)

Answer (score 0):

My kernel, [K-OS](https://github.com/escortkeel/k-os), does this.

Basically, you need to write a linker script to shift your whole kernel to the desired "Higher-half" address (see [this](https://github.com/escortkeel/k-os/blob/master/kernel/src/linker.ld.S)). Then, you need to append a little assembler snippet (see [this](https://github.com/escortkeel/k-os/blob/master/kernel/src/loader.s)) which is the kernel's entry point.

This snippet should **only use relative addresses** and should set up the page tables for higher half (map the whole kernel to where you said it would be in the linker script). Finally, that snippet should JMP to the "Higher-half" entry point and then call into C code.